# Regex for real numbers Java

Tags: java, regex

I was trying to write a simple regex to match real numbers which is like this:

```
[+-]?[\\d]+[\\.]?[\\d]*
```

Explanation for sequence of regex - An optional + or - sign , 1 or more digits ,optional period, 0 or more digits

The problem is it is matching a String if it contains a single digit in it (e.g. a match is found for abc23). But I want to match only real numbers.

Comment: your regex also matches `56.`, is this a valid number?

Comment: Do you also want `0.5e-5` to parse?

Answer (score 1):

Use the below regex in `matches` method.

```
[+-]?\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?
```

Code:

```
System.out.println("abc".matches("[+-]?\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?"));
System.out.println("abc123".matches("[+-]?\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?"));
System.out.println("12.".matches("[+-]?\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?"));
System.out.println("+65657".matches("[+-]?\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?"));
System.out.println("-8.99".matches("[+-]?\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?"));
```

Output:

```
false
false
false
true
true
```

The output of third example is `false` because the numbers ended with a dot. I think this is not quite right.

Comment: op's regex would match `78.`, but it won't.

Answer (score 0):

Your have to use this pattern

#### Pattern

```
^[+-]?[\d]+[\.]?[\d]*$/gm
```

#### Explanation

```
 ^       -  Begin character
 [+-]?   -  ? means optional either + or - sign if have otherwise not a compulsory
 [\d]+   -  Allow Digit number and + extend any number of digit
 [\.]?   -  Allow period sign (.), optional
 [\d]*   -  Allow Digit number and * specifies 0 or more
 $       -  Ending of the string
 /gm     -  Matching global, multiline
```

#### Check on <kbd>**[Regexr](http://www.regexr.com/39gea)**</kbd>

Comment: Why are you using class character instead of the character by itself?

Comment: @M42 i don't understand what r u saying me. explain me details. thanks

Comment: Why using `[\d]` instead of `\d`?

Comment: Yes you can use any one [\d] or \d